# JQuery manipulating Body Element within a Frame Tag/Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frames

I'm trying to manipulate the  element inside of a  tag.  Is there a way to do this?
Here's the code:

```
<frame id="foo" name="myFrame" src="http://google.com" frameborder="0">
#document
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
</frame>
```

Ideally, when the page loads, I would like to add the message "Please wait..." in the  element.  I tried using JQuery to do this but can't get it to work correct.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        var f=$('#foo');
        alert(f.contents().find('body'));
        f.contents().find('body').add('Please Wait....');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: its not possible to alter elements in a frame of another domain. see http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Comment: @Alex not entirely true ... you can if you control both domains

Comment: @charlietfl lol yes, it is true. the browser does not know who controls the domain. as soon as the protocol or domain differs, you get an error. and you should.

Comment: @Alex there are several ways if you have ability to put script in iframe page (control both domains). One is setting `document.domain` , another is postMessage API.

Comment: but you can not alter contents of a differnt-domain-iframe?!

Comment: sure you can if you have window to window communications. First one I mentioned allows direct access to frame window as if it wasn't corss domain. With postMessage you can pass data and use event handlers to do what you want

Comment: yes - if you own the two domains, as you said. the op didnt really tell anything about this so whatever

Comment: just mentioning it so the `impossible` isn't taken as a blanket statement